# Field Tracking does not Capture Field updates through Batch Job

Tags: configuration, history-tracking

I have enabled Field Tracking on the Status field of Asset Object. There is a Batch Job which updates the Status based on the UsageEndDate of the record. But somehow the Updates of the Batch Job are not getting captured in the Asset History Tracking.

I have checked when I manually update the records using the same user which is used to schedule the Batch Job the history is tracked on the same field. Could not find any restriction by SFDC which says History tracking does not work for Batch Jobs.

Appreciate your response on this if I am missing something.

Regards

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Have you checked with support?